# How do I connect internal corporate github repo to heroku?

Tags: heroku, github, github-enterprise

I was following guidelines and tried to connect heroku to a github repo within our own corporate github (the github url differs from the standard one). Yet, I couldn't find a proper way to do so – clicking on this button would redirect me to github.com, and not git.companyname.com:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to tackle this issue? Do I need to go to internal github and manually add heroku as OAuth application?

Comment: You may need to do this in GitHub https://developer.github.com/guides/automating-deployments-to-integrators/

Comment: thank you, @osowskit. Yes, I've figured that. Why wouldn't you submit your comment as an answer, so you could get extra kudos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, Heroku does not integrate well with internal enterprise github. In my case I have two remote destinations in my git: one is for github, another one is for heroku, and I push the code changes to both remote endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

I was researching this as well, and found a workaround: add your heroku repo as a remote, and the code can auto deploy once you pushed to that remote:

```
git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/your-repo.git
```

Then you should be able to push to it via:

```
git push heroku master
```

And your code will be auto-deployed.