# How do I connect my university (enterprise) GitHub for CI with my Heroku app

Tags: github, heroku

Heroku seems to only allow public Github.com repos.[image: Heroku]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I connect internal corporate github repo to heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604184/how-do-i-connect-internal-corporate-github-repo-to-heroku)

Comment: @RamonMedeiros well it doesn't I guess. I am able to deploy the app but I wanted a CI pipeline to the application so code get pushed for each commit.